# Custom off-topic close reasons

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

We can set up to 3 custom close reasons. Do we want any custom close reasons?

From [What do site moderators need to do to support the new custom question close reasons?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184637/what-do-site-moderators-need-to-do-to-support-the-new-custom-question-close-reas/185097#185097):

> This can be tricky; your goal here is to communicate clearly with the people whose questions are being closed, with the people who are closing questions *and* with the people who will later read those questions and wonder why they were closed.
>
> At a bare minimum, **off-topic reasons should identify a *specific* topic considered inappropriate**. If you're struggling to be specific, find an example of a question that is off-topic and discuss the factors that make it inappropriate for the site.
>
> Whenever possible, **try to explain *why* a given topic is not allowed** - this is your chance to answer the inevitable question *once* rather than repeating it every time a question must be closed.
>
> **Provide resources that will aid askers in solving their problems**: either instructions for asking the question in a more suitable fashion, links to a different site where the question may be considered on-topic.
>
> **Be as concise as possible**. Save *lengthy* explanations and examples for meta FAQs that can be discussed and refined over time, and then include links to these in the off-topic reasons. Don't depend on anyone following these links though; keep critical information and guidance in the reason text itself.
>
> Do all of this on your meta site so that folks can critique the wording and suggest improvements.

Comment: How many posts have been closed with generalizable reasons so far? The reason to have site-specific predefined close reasons is for cases that come up often, not just for the sake of it. Generally these are reasons that have been identified in a meta discussion from which a policy has emerged that a certain type of questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 9):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

The "can no longer be reproduced" error reason from Stack Overflow:

> This question was caused by a problem that can **no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Candidates for questions that can be closed with this reason:

- [Unite file_rec search misses a file](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3092/unite-file-rec-search-misses-a-file)
- [Trouble sourcing files from .nvimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3053/trouble-sourcing-files-from-nvimrc)
- [<C-z> on gvim (windows) hides the window instead of decrementing the number on cursor](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3154/c-z-on-gvim-windows-hides-the-window-instead-of-decrementing-the-number-on-c)
- [How to set up NERDTree to CD to current folder when opening it for the first time](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2969/how-to-set-up-nerdtree-to-cd-to-current-folder-when-opening-it-for-the-first-tim)

Comment: Maybe instead of typographical error could this be changed to "Issued caused by plugin/vimrc"? There are a lot of issues that are posted that are either due to plugins changing standard functionality or the user made a change to their vimrc and forgot/didn't understand what it was doing.

Answer (score -1):

The "is a bug report" reason from Ask Ubuntu:

> **Bug reports** and **problems specific to development version of Ubuntu** should be reported on Launchpad so that developers can see, track and fix these issues.

Adapted:

> **Bug reports** should be reported at the
>   appropriate place so that developers can see, track and fix these
>   issues. See [`:help bug-reports`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#bug-reports) for Vim, and consult the
>   appropriate issue tracker for plugins.

Candidate(s) for questions that can be closed with this reason:

- The original version of https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2898/how-can-i-make-vim-airlines-tabline-coexist-with-vims-tabline
- [How to prevent vim-jsx from mangling my indentation?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3228/205)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good one ... Often it's not at all obvious that a problem is a bug from the question itself, and if it isn't, I think an answer with "This is a bug" can be acceptable ... There may also be answers that work around the bug or offer alternative solutions.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker working around a bug is always on topic. That's why I reworded my question in the example cited. In that case, I wasn't originally aware that the problem was a plugin. romainl's comment made me aware of that, and also of his feeling that this should be posted on the plugin bug tracker. After rewording, I feel my question is asking for a workaround.

Comment: I see both sides of this. On the one hand, this isn't a bug tracker. On the other hand, people who run into a problem and search for how to deal with it should be able to find either a work around or at least information that a bug exists and a pointer to where it is tracked, which could be useful even after the bug itself is fixed, since many people use older versions of packages and plugins. I could see this close-reason as being an indicator that a question needs to be reworded, but that could result in the loss of information that an issue is caused by a bug.

Comment: @JohnO'M. Consider it similar to an "unclear what you're asking" closure - editing it could (probably would) have it reopened.

Comment: I'm surprised by "problems specific to plugins"--I thought questions about plugins were welcome on vi.SE. If by "problems" you mean *bugs*, then I think this could be made clearer.

Comment: @Rich that was just me quickly adapting the original phrasing. Please, feel free to edit

Comment: @muru Ah cool. In that case I think you'd probably be fine removing the "and problems specific to plugins" part entirely.

Comment: @Rich I suppose so. The last clause covers the "bugs in plugins" part, so that phase doesn't need to be there.